# How can I replace a string in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to do a simple string substitution, but could not succeed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$var = "M4S120_appscan";
$var1 = "SCANS";

$path =~ s/$var/$var1/;

print "Path is $path"
```

The output should be `"Path is SCANS"`, but it prints nothing in 'output'.

Comment: Why not just `print "Path is $var1"`? What is the substitution supposed to do?

Comment: That was a example created by me.  I need to do similar replacement in 'live script'

Comment: Been a while since I did perl but isn't $var just going to be treated as a literal string that's part of the regex?

Comment: Not sure what you want to do. Is it "Path is M4S120_appscan" replace to "Path is SCANS"?

Comment: @Deqing  Yes, I want to replace 'M4S120_appscan" to "SCANS" through variables.  That's all

Comment: If you have just started learning Perl, please use `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every program you write. If your tutorial/book does not have that, it is massively outdated. Take a look at [the Perl tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info) instead. There are very good up to date resources linked there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The substitution operator, `s///`, takes three arguments: the string, in which we want to do replacement, in your example is a `$path` variable, the search term (`$var`) and the replacement, `$var1`.

As you can see, you try to replace "M4S120_appscan" with "SCANS" inside an empty string, because $path is not initialized. You need to initialize $path before doing replacement, for example:

```
$path = "M4S120_appscan";
```

Answer (score 13):

To replace "M4S120_appscan" with "SCANS" in a string:

```
$str = "Path is M4S120_appscan";
$find = "M4S120_appscan";
$replace = "SCANS";
$str =~ s/$find/$replace/;
print $str;
```

If this is what you want.

Comment: Does this work if `$find` or `$replace` contain special characters? Why not `$str =~ s/M4S120_appscan/SCANS/`? (maybe with `/g` to replace all, not just the first match)

Answer (score 1):

Substitution is a regular expression search and replace. Kindly [follow Thilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050930/how-to-replace-string-in-perl#comment59750082_36050930):

```
$var = "M4S120_appscan";
$var =~ s/M.+\_.+can/SCANS/g;  # /g replaces all matches
print "path is $var";
```